# Topological and algebraic interiors

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I read on a functional analysis book that in a normed, real or complex, space $V$ the algebraic interior of a set $S\subset V$ defined $J(S):=\{x\in S:\quad\forall y\in V\quad\exists \varepsilon(y)=\varepsilon>0:\forall t\in\mathbb{R}(|t|<\varepsilon\Rightarrow x+ty\in S)\}$ is the same of its topological interior $\mathring{S}$.
I'm convinced that it is not true in general for a normed, either real or complex, vector space, but I see that for any such normed space the inclusion $\mathring{S}\subset J(S)$ is true, and I have also found the [proof](http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/libor/AnConvessa/interno_top_alg.pdf) that, if $S$ is convex, then $\mathring{S}= J(S)$ holds in such spaces.

Can it be proven, and how, that $\mathring{S}\subset J(S)$ in any topological vector space?
If $S$ is convex, can it be proven, and how, that $\mathring{S}= J(S)$?

I'm tremendously confused because my book states $\mathring{S}= J(S)$ for normed spaces and then appears to use the equality at least for convex sets, not only in normed spaces, but in general locally convex spaces...

$\infty$ thanks for any answer!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always have the inclusion $\overset{\Large\circ}{S} \subset J(S)$, but equality does not generally hold.

$J(S)$ is the set of points $x$ such that $S-x = \{s-x : s\in S\}$ is an *absorbing* set, and $\overset{\Large\circ}{S}$ is the set of points $x$ such that $S-x$ is a neighbourhood of $0$. Since every neighbourhood of $0$ is absorbing, the inclusion $\overset{\Large\circ}{S} \subset J(S)$ follows.

Equality does generally not hold even for convex sets, for that would mean that every convex absorbing set be a neighbourhood of $0$, and that only holds for the finest locally convex topology, not for others.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!! Great answer, based on something you know I know. ;-) $\aleph_1$ thanks!